# Where can I download iOS 8.4 Beta safely, and how do I install it?

Tags: ios

I've just seen a [video on the new Music app in iOS 8.4 Beta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkGem8NjX8o). Now if possible I would like to try it, so I simply googled *"iOS 8.4 Beta download"*. I was hoping to find it in some developer section of an Apple website, but only found it on third party websites.
Can I assume that the software is going to be safe, when downloading it from websites like [Chip.de](http://www.chip.de/downloads/iOS-8.4-Beta_70175653.html) (which is usually a trustworthy source).
How would I go about installing the software, as there are normally updates in iTunes or on the iOS device itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 8.4 is not an open beta, so you have to be registered Apple developer (99$ a year) to use beta software on your iOS device.

Also note that getting the software-package is not enough. You're devices UID has to be registered with apple so it will activate when you install the beta software.

Comment: Ah, too bad for me then :D

Comment: There's also the golden rule - never install beta software on any mission-critical device ;)